# linux: selective sudo access for a particular command

Tags: shutdown, sudo, remote-shutdown

Is it possible to grant a particular user sudo access for one particular command only?

Thanks

--

More info:

We farm out lengthy optimisation runs to each other's boxes over ssh. These runs take hours, sometimes days.

The shutdown command can only be run in sudo. Being conscious of my environmental footprint, I would like to give the initiator(s) of these runs sudo access to the shutdown command on my box, without sudo access for everything else - so that they may shutdown my machine when they no longer need it.

I am aware that I can schedule a shutdown *before* I leave my box, but I am looking for a better solution.

Comment: Can we assume you haven't looked at the docs?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams : which docs are you referring to?

Comment: The `sudoers(5)` man page.

Comment: Consider accepting the (seemingly correct) answer, or comment on what doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
visudo
```

as root, and add

```
%admin ALL = NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown
```

to the end of the file, then

- add the user to admin group

and you can run "sudo shutdown -h now" from the user.

or rather, chmod 4755 the shutdown command.